# How to give a textbox gradient color in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, gradient

Hey I need help to give my textbox a gradient color.
I know that I can give the actual WIndows Form a gradient color but I just can figure out how to give the textbox that I want?

Please help me :)

Comment: That's not possible.  Switch to WPF if these kind of doodahs are important to you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the BackColor of the sex box to transparent and putting it in another control on which you paint the gradient?

Answer (score 3):

you can check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/fbdd1e74-4ad9-40ae-9458-3339640948c3) out. It must help you.